# Grammar joke with Tornado statement in the html page

Tags: python, if-statement, tornado

I have a grammar problem.

I have this Tornado statement in my html page:

```
{% if usrperm > 2 %}
```

where *usrperm* is an integer passed from the Tornado handler to the page. I would compare this value and show a *div* block only if this value is bigger than 2. But this statement didn't work.

If I print the *usrperm* variable I have this:

**[{'perm': 1L}]**

So where I mistake? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously `usrperm` is not a interger, but a dictionary. So your check should probably look like this:

```
{% if usrperm[0]['perm'] > 2 %}
```

In general you should provide more details to get better answers. Exceptions details are more helpful than "didn't work". And it would also be helpful to see the code which passes the data to tornado.

Comment: I have this error `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: @sharkbait Then you want `usrperm[0]['perm']`

Comment: Jon if you write this in an answer I can tick this like the right answer! :) Thank you very much!!

Comment: Thank you very much to both of us! You're my heroes!